# How to edit a variable that is inside a function that I cannot edit directly

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a function that I am unable to edit directly because the software I am using automatically outputs this code and I am unable to access it. I want to override one of the variables in the code. I have access to add code into the footer. I would like to change the variable for Goal to the number 2000, is that possible without being able do directly edit the function?

```
var goal = parseCurrency(jQuery('#374ec6b5_thermometer .total-goal-value').text());
```

If I can change this pull from a different div or set this to the number 2000 that would be awesome. Let me know if this is not enough info or if it just isnt possible. Thanks!

```js
Y.use("jquery-ui", function(Y) {
  jQuery(function() {
    var calcThermPercentage = function() {
      // calculate the thermometer percentage
      var raised = parseCurrency(jQuery('#374ec6b5_thermometer .amount-raised-value').text());
      var goal = parseCurrency(jQuery('#374ec6b5_thermometer .total-goal-value').text());
      var percent = raised / goal;
      if (percent > 1) {
        percent = 1;
      }
      var percentage = percent;
      if (isNaN(percentage)) {
        percentage = 0;
      }
      jQuery('#374ec6b5_thermometer .amount-percentage-value').text(Math.floor(percentage * 100) + "%");
      // get the width of the outer container;
      var outerWidth = jQuery('#374ec6b5_thermometer .thermometer-outer').css('width').slice(0, -2);
      var innerWidth = outerWidth * percent;
      jQuery('#374ec6b5_thermometer .thermometer-inner').animate({
        'width': innerWidth + 'px'
      }, 1000);
    };
    calcThermPercentage();
    var waitForFinalEvent = (function() {
      var timers = {};
      return function(callback, ms, uniqueId) {
        if (!uniqueId) {
          uniqueId = "default_unique_id";
        }
        if (timers[uniqueId]) {
          clearTimeout(timers[uniqueId]);
        }
        timers[uniqueId] = setTimeout(callback, ms);
      };
    })();
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
      waitForFinalEvent(calcThermPercentage, 500, "374ec6b5");
    });
  });
});

function parseCurrency(currency) {
  currency = currency.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, "");
  var val = parseInt(currency);
  return val;
}
```

Comment: only way is to redefine the function.

Comment: Please format your posted code properly, it's pretty hard to read like that. You cannot change the variable without changing the function, as the function will always override your changes when executed.

Comment: maybe just try to set the value on the selector element ('#374ec6b5_thermometer .total-goal-value') to 2000 instead

Comment: if the function is global, you can .toString() it to a variable, search & replace whatever you want. and then eval() it. else, i'm afraid you will have to capture the JS content, change whatever you want to change, $.loadScript() your edited copy.